# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516209/conjecture-lfloor-fracn4-rfloor-lfloor-fracn14-rfloor-lfloor-fracn2) question a few days ago, where I noticed $$\left\lfloor\frac{n}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}4\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}4\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}4\right\rfloor=\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-1,\quad n\in\mathbb N$$

We can also write $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-1=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}$, and so I decided to try and evaluate $$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}k$$

to perhaps arrive at a another equivalence between trigonometric and floor functions(I do realise that we are only using trivial values of the cosine, but nevertheless find it rather intriguing).

---

I have arrived at a trigonometric relation as follows:

Since $\sum_{k=1}^nka_k=n(a_1+a_2+\dots+ a_n)-\sum_{k=1}^n(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{k-1})$, we have (for $a_k=(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}$ )

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^nk(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}&=n\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-1\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)-1\right)\\
&=n\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-\frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}4)}{\sin\frac\pi4}\cdot\cos\frac{(n-1)\pi}4\\
&=n\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\sin\frac{(2n-1)\pi}4-\frac12
\end{align}$$

While not as concise as I had hoped, it is still a simple trigonometric equation. My problem however, lies in somehow generating a floor function evaluation for the series. Could somebody please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I disagree with $\cos(n\pi/2)-1=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k(k+1)/2}$, I think you need to sum from $k=1$.

Comment: @FShrike Yes my bad! I will fix it

Comment: Have you tried substituting $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1$ and simplifying? It's not a difficult sum, just $0-1-2+3+4-5-6+7+8-9-10+11+\dots$ that evaluates to $0,-1,-3,0,4,-1,-7,0,8,-1,-11,0,\dots$. So, if we denote the value of the sum by $f(n)$, then $f(4k)=4k$, $f(4k+1)=-1$, $f(4k+2)=-4k-3$, $f(4k+3)=0$. You can now collect these cases into a single formula if you wish.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein I did notice that the sum evaluates to $n,-1,-n-3,0$ in repeating patterns for some $n\equiv0\mod4$, but that involves changing into a definition by parts. I don't see how to combine all that into a single formula either

Comment: Maybe use something like $(1+(-1)^n)/2$ to get $1,0,1,0,\dots$, and $(1-(-1)^n)/2$ to get $0,1,0,1,\dots$, that might help. Note that $(n,-1,-n-1,0)=n(1,0,-1,0)+(0,-1,-1,0)$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein I will try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write the series as $$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)} 2}k=\sum_{4j\le n}4j+\sum_{4j-1\le n}(4j-1)-\sum_{4j-2\le n}(4j-2)-\sum_{4j-3\le n}(4j-3)$$

Since $$\sum_{4j\le n}4j=\left(4+8+\dots+4\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor\right)=\frac12\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor\left(2\cdot4+\left(\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor-1\right)\cdot4\right)$$

$$\implies\sum_{4j\le n}4j=2\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor^2+2\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor$$

We can use this result to evaluate the remaining terms as :
$$\sum_{4j-1\le n}(4j-1)=\sum_{4j\le n+1}4j-\sum_{4j\le n+1}1=2\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor^2+2\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor$$
$$\implies\sum_{4j-1\le n}(4j-1)=2\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor$$

Similarly,
$$\sum_{4j-2\le n}(4j-2)=2\left\lfloor\frac {n+2}4\right\rfloor^2,\sum_{4j-3\le n}(4j-3)=2\left\lfloor\frac {n+3}4\right\rfloor^2-\left\lfloor\frac {n+3}4\right\rfloor$$

Thus,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)} 2}k=2\left(\left\lfloor\frac {n}4\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor^2-\left\lfloor\frac {n+2}4\right\rfloor^2-\left\lfloor\frac {n+3}4\right\rfloor^2\right)\\+2\left\lfloor\frac {n}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {n+3}4\right\rfloor$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\begin{align} n\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\sin\frac{(2n-1)\pi}4-\frac12=&2\left(\left\lfloor\frac {n}4\right\rfloor^2 +\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor^2-\left\lfloor\frac {n+2}4\right\rfloor^2-\left\lfloor\frac {n+3}4\right\rfloor^2\right)\\&+2\left\lfloor\frac {n}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {n+1}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {n+3}4\right\rfloor \end{align}}$$